# Chatting with PDFs using Lang chain

Tags: python-3.x, openai-api, azure-openai, py-langchain, faiss

```
'''
bot.gpt_turbo = Model_LLM(OPENAI_DEPLOYMENT_NAME, openai.api_version).model

embeddings = OpenAIEmbeddings(model=OPENAI_EMBEDDING_MODEL_NAME)

fileLoaded = FileLoader("Data/filename.pdf", TokenTextSplitter(chunk_size=1000, chunk_overlap=1))

text = fileLoaded.load_file()
#vectorStore = Chroma.from_documents(text,embedding=embeddings)
vectorStore = FAISS.from_documents(text,embedding=embeddings)

qa = RetrievalEngine(llm=bot.gpt_turbo, retriever=vectorStore.as_retriever(),chain_type="stuff")

#query = "Please give me the list of sampleID"

while True:
    askQuestion  = input("Ask me a question about the file?: ")
    print(qa.initialize_qa_engine().run(askQuestion))
'''
```

I am getting an error on FAISS.from_documents(). "openai.error.InvalidRequestError: Must provide an 'engine' or 'deployment_id' parameter to create a <class 'openai.api_resources.embedding.Embedding'>"
I tried everything and did they change something recently? This code works fine before.

Comment: I tried it with chroma.from_documents() and I have the same issue. Anyone have a solution for this?